# How to add ignored files into heroku?

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, heroku

I have a php app into heroku. I use the free version. My app use codeigniter framework and I need ignore some files with a gitignore, for example I have a file database.php with the information of the database connection's. That information is different in each enviroment, my question is, how can upload these kind of files into heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to solve your problem. Any config information like:

- api keys
- database host / password
- any other specific env configuration

shouldn't be versionned in git.

You should use environment variables. I assume you want to use different database host/username/password whether you're in development environment (your working directory), in staging, or in production.

1) Check how to set environment variables (it's different between Windows and Linux/Mac OS X), but you have helpers and it's a good practice to use that (even more when using heroku)

2) Since you're using php, you'll be able to retrieve those variable with [getenv](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.getenv.php). You should have something like :

```
$dbUserName = getenv('DB_USER_NAME');
$dbHost = getenv('DB_HOST');
$dbPassword = getenv('DB_PASSWORD');

//use the variables above to make a db connexion
```

3) Time to set the env variables on your heroku vm ([see more](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars))

```
$ heroku config:set DB_USER_NAME=foo
$ heroku config:set DB_HOST=bar
$ heroku config:set DB_PASSWORD=fee
```

Your code will automatically use the correct config when you'll push to heroku (you won't have to bother to have to change something on your code base between your dev env and your production env + each team member can have different config on their local dev machine)